# Setting OnClickListener on items inside of ListView Item in Custom Adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have created a custom Adapter for list which different items and each item has a button to invite. The item should flip horizontally when the respective invite button is clicked and that is working fine. The problem is that when I click invite button of first item then invite button of 4th item is also clicked. I am attaching the code hee

```
package rovoltlabs.coffeechat.adapters;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import rovoltlabs.coffeechat.R;
import rovoltlabs.coffeechat.animation.AnimationFactory;
import rovoltlabs.coffeechat.animation.AnimationFactory.FlipDirection;
import rovoltlabs.coffeechat.volley.utils.Const;
import rovoltslabs.coffeechat.app.AppController;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewAnimator;

import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

    Context contexts;
    List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> slots = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> heading = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> showtime = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Bitmap> img = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    List<ViewHolder> myview = new ArrayList<ViewHolder>();
    private String tag_json_obj = "jobj_req";

    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    View row;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, List<String> name,
            List<Bitmap> img, List<String> heading, List<String> slots,
            List<String> id) {
        super();
        this.contexts = context;
        this.name = name;
        this.img = img;
        this.heading = heading;
        this.slots = slots;
        this.ids = id;

        mLayoutInflater = ((Activity) contexts).getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // check to see if the reused view is null or not, if is not null then
        // reuse it
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
            holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Name);
            holder.fname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.flipName);
            holder.msg = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.fsend);
            holder.heading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ddheading);
            holder.distance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Distance);
            holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagecoffee);
            holder.invite = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.inviteButton);
            holder.send = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.fsendButton);
            holder.time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timefree);
            holder.viewAnimator = (ViewAnimator) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
            myview.add(holder);
            holder.v = view;

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        }
        view.setTag(holder);
        holder.invite.setOnClickListener(this);


        holder.send.setOnClickListener(this);

        holder.name.setText(name.get(position).split("\n")[0]);
        holder.fname.setText(name.get(position).split("\n")[0]);
        holder.heading.setText(heading.get(position));
        String temp = "";
        int sl = Integer.parseInt(slots.get(position));
        if (sl % 2 == 0) {
            temp = "" + ((sl / 2) - 1) + ":30 - " + ((sl / 2)) + ":00";
        } else {
            temp = "" + ((sl / 2)) + ":00-" + ((sl / 2)) + ":30";
        }

        holder.time.setText(temp);

        holder.distance.setText(name.get(position).split("\n")[1] + " m");
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(img.get(position));

        holder.invite.setTag(position);
        holder.send.setTag(position);

        return view;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {

        protected TextView name;
        protected TextView heading;
        protected TextView distance, time;
        protected ImageView image;
        protected Button invite, send;
        protected View v;
        protected ViewAnimator viewAnimator;
        protected TextView fname;
        protected EditText msg;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v.getId() == R.id.inviteButton) {

            AnimationFactory.flipTransition(
                    myview.get((Integer) v.getTag()).viewAnimator,
                    FlipDirection.LEFT_RIGHT);


        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.fsend) {
            SharedPreferences pref = contexts.getApplicationContext()
                    .getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
            String slotsss = "{\"slots\":[" + slots.get((Integer) v.getTag())
                    + "]}";
            final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("slot", slotsss);
            Log.e("invite slots", slotsss);
            params.put("to", ids.get((Integer) v.getTag()));
            params.put("from", pref.getString("id", "N/A"));
            params.put("message", myview.get((Integer) v.getTag()).msg
                    .getText().toString());
            StringRequest jsonObjReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                    Const.URL_INVITE, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Log.d("Slots Response: ", response.toString());
                            Toast.makeText(contexts, "invited" + response,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            VolleyLog.d("invite Error:",
                                    "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                        }
                    }) {

                /**
                 * Passing some request headers
                 * */

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                    return params;
                }

            };

            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq,
                    tag_json_obj);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried by creating different listeners?

And one minor change for your your good.

Put  view.setTag(holder); inside if block.

Comment: Why don't you set your `onClickListener` inside `getView()` method?

Comment: Tried putting it inside if block. still having same issue.

Comment: I tried putting onClickListener inside getView() still getting same problem.

Comment: Are both your first and fourth items visible at the same time so you are seeing both animations happen simultaneously?

Comment: No they are not visible simultaneously. I think items are recycling, I don't know exactly

Comment: OK, that definitely explains it then.  I'll add an answer shortly.

Comment: Put view.setTag(holder); in if(view == null){} block.

Answer (score 0):

The `View` objects are recycling and you're using the same `ViewHolder` object (and other UI components) for both positions.  The view being clicked has had its tag updated to the position desired, but the animation object is the same as another position due to the recycling.

Comment: can you please elaborate where should I change my code.

Comment: If the 2nd view isn't visible, how do you know both are receiving onClick notifications and animations running?

Comment: coz when I scroll down I see the item flipped.

Comment: Without seeing your custom animation its difficult to say exactly, but my guess is that what you are seeing is the finished state of the animation.  So when the view hierarchy is recycled, the child views are all in their final state from the animation.  On the recycle case you'll need to reset your animation state back to the starting point.  If this is just 2 views with visibility and position translation changed, you'll need to reset them.  I'd also recommend putting your data into an object and track a single list rather than multiple ones (name, slots, heading, etc.)

Comment: Its not coz of that I think (maybe I am wrong). when I try to type something on the edittext of first item it also write on the 4th item. whatever I do to the first item the same thing happens to 4th one.